# how to get substring, starting from the first occurence of a pattern in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to get a substring from the start of a pattern.

I would simply use `cut`, but it wouldn't work if the pattern is a few characters long.

if I needed a single-character, delimiter, then this would do the trick:

```
result=`echo "test String with ( element in parenthesis ) end" | cut -d "(" -f 2-`
```

**edit: sample tests:**

```
 INPUT: ("This test String is an input", "in")
 OUTPUT: "ing is an input"

 INPUT: ("This test string is an input", "in ")
 OUTPUT: ""

 INPUT: ("This test string is an input", "n")
 OUTPUT: "ng is an input"
```

note: the parenthesis mean that the input both takes a string, and a delimiter string.

Comment: What is your desired output? I am unclear on the exact question.

Comment: the desired output is a subsection of the original string, starting at the first exact match with the pattern, and ending at the end of the original string.

Comment: Still not clear - can you provide TWO text pasts one with SAMPLE-INPUT and one with SAMPLE-OUTPUT?  Giving us an example of something that does not work only points at a general direction.

Comment: edited. I apologize if my question isn't too clear - hopefully its better now

Comment: So you want to pass in that entire set of text, including the brackets and quotation marks, as an argument?

Comment: yes. and if they are between the delimiter and the end, I also want to obtain them in the output string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED:

In conclusion, what was requested was a way to parse out the text from a string beginning at a particular substring and ending at the end of the line. As mentioned, there are numerous ways to do this. Here's one...

`egrep -o "DELIM.*" input`

... where 'DELIM' is the desired substring.

Comment: not exactly - I'm looking to find a substring STARTING at one delimiter, and ending at the end of the string (sure, I can assume the \n delimiter).   I've added a few examples to make my question clearer.

Comment: Hmm, do you mean you want to be able to get the string beginning from your multi-char delimiter until the end of the line? If so, there are multiple different ways to do it. Here's one, assuming your delimiter is 'DELIM'...

`sed 's/.*\(DELIM.*\)/\1/' input`

Comment: not exactly - First you assume the string ens with ")"  - while it can be anything, and second,`invalid reference \1 on 's' command's RHS`

Comment: No, the brackets in this case are not part of searched string, they're special characters used by `sed`. How about trying this instead: `egrep -o "DELIM.*" input`. If it works, let me know and I'll edit my answer above.

Comment: perfect! thanks. can you change your answer to this, so I can mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: Nice. Glad you got what you needed. =)

Answer (score 0):

Also

```
awk -v delim="in" '{print substr($0, index($0, delim))}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without external programs. Assuming the string to be processed is in `$string` and the delimiter is `DELIM`:

```
result=${string#"${string%%DELIM*}"}
```

The inner part substitutes `$string` with everything starting from the first occurrence of `DELIM` (if any) removed. The outer part then removes that value from the start of `$string`, leaving everything starting from the first occurrence of `DELIM` or the empty string if `DELIM` does not occur. (The variable `string` remains unchanged.)

Comment: how to achieve the exact opposite of this?